# Where do I have to specify the sub-route I want my Vite project to run on?

Tags: node.js, webserver, config, svelte, vite

I have a Svelte + Vue project which I want to be available on a sub-route ('/game') of my webserver.

I had this problem a few years ago with Vue and was able to find the solution, but cannot find it anymore.
I can't find the option here (where I think it should be theoretically). https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the [`base` option](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#base) (different section of the docs).